# Как сделать кнопку активной и неактивной

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.

Вот у меня настигла такая проблема связанная с тем, что мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, до того как анимация закончиться кнопка была в неактивном состоянии. Я скачал готовую галерею и подстраиваю под себя. Вот сам код, который реализует все события после нажатия на кнопку.

```
     if(o.btnNext){
            $(o.btnNext).bind(o.evtStart, function() {
        if(defaultBtn){ o.btnNext.css('opacity',0.9);  }
        running = true;
        next_button(index+1,kol);
        index++;
        if (index>=kol) index= index-kol;
        direction = 'forward';
    //-----------------------------------------------------
      pressed_next = true;
      pressedNext(pressed_next);
    //---------------------------------------------------
        return forward();
            });
          $(o.btnNext).bind(o.evtStop,function() {
          if(defaultBtn){ o.btnNext.css('opacity',0.6); }
          running = false;
          direction = null;
          return stop();
        });
     }

 function forward(stepsize, once){
        var s = (stepsize ? stepsize : step);
            if(running === true && direction === "backward"){ return; }

            //If not circular, no need to animate endlessly
            if(!o.circular){
                //will the next step overtake the last  image ?
                if(curr + s + (o.vertical ? divVSize : divSize) > eltsSize){
                    s = eltsSize - (curr + (o.vertical ? divVSize : divSize));
                }
            }
            ul.animate(

                 animCss == "left" ? { left: -(curr + s) } : { top: -(curr + s) } , o.speed, o.easing,
                 function() {

                    curr += s; //Add step size
                    //Calculate whether we cross the limit,
                    //if so, put the carousel one time backward
                    if(o.circular){

                        if(curr + (o.vertical ? divVSize : divSize) + liSize >= allEltsSize){
                              ul.css(o.vertical ? 'top' : 'left', -curr + eltsSize);
                              curr -= eltsSize;
                        }
                    }

                     if(!once && running){
                         forward();
                     }
                     else if(once){
                        if(--mousewheelN > 0){
                            this.forward(step, true);
                        }
                        else{
                             running = false;
                             direction = null;
                        }
                     }
                 }
             ); 
            //_______________________
            pressed_next = false;
                  pressedNext(pressed_next);
                  //_____________________
         }

 function stop(){
            if(!o.eltByElt){    
                ul.stop();      
                curr = 0 - parseInt(ul.css(animCss));   
            }
            running = false;    
            direction = null;
    }
```

Это то, что я добавил процедура которая блокирует кнопки.

```
 function pressedNext(pressed_next){
    if (pressed_next){
                      o.btnNext ='disabled';
                    }
            else{
                      o.btnNext='enabled';
                    }   
 }
```

Правильно ли я написал, чтобы блокировать кнопку или нет, `disabled` и `enabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(o.btnNext){
$(o.btnNext).bind(o.evtStart, function() {
var current = $(this);
if(current.hasClass('in-process')){
console.log('Button next: FALSE');
return false
}
else {
console.log('Button next: GO');
current.addClass('in-process').css('opacity', 0.3);
running = true;
direction = 'forward';
forward(current); 
return stop(); 
    }  });
И еще добавить в forward/backward после ul.animate(function() {
clickedButton.css('opacity', 0.9).removeClass('in-process');

Answer (score 0):

Правильно или нет, а вы проверяли код сами или нет? Вы присваиваете `o.btnNext`, которая содержит ссылку на элемент строковое значение `disabled`, конечно это не правильно.

Comment: Проверял... ошибку дает на o.btnNext='enabled';o.btnNext='disabled'; как правильно прописать

Comment: Смотря чем является o.btnNext, скорей всего это просто ссылка, в таком случае тебе нужно на клик проверять если у нее класс disabled, если он есть то return false, а если нет (первый клик), то вешаешь класс, через цсс делаешь его приглушенным или каким там надо, плюс само дальнейшее действие. Затем в конце анимации убираешь этот класс

Comment: Я вроде так и делаю, чего то у меня не получается, опять еще какие то ошибки ... может я не так делаю ...  <br> можешь зайти в ICQ 363693128 <br> 
murad_2008.88@mail.ru

Comment: вот ссылка на сам файл <br>
http://file.qip.ru/file/nLO7bAYD/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Это я понял а вот  disabled он чего брать,раз o.btnNext это ссылка
o.btnPrev = defaultBtn ? $('<input type="button" class="' + (o.vertical ? 'up' : 'prev') + '"/>') : $(o.btnPrev);
o.btnNext = defaultBtn ? $('<input type="button" class="' + (o.vertical ? 'down' : 'next') + '"/>') : $(o.btnNext);
        var prev = o.btnPrev;
        var next = o.btnNext;
Вот сами кнопки